# Android TV app is not visible in store on the device

Tags: android, television

I have developed nice useful web browser for Android TV, it is getting traction and nice feedback from the community. Since I am very experienced developer it will only get better and more rich with features. App has of course passed all the additional reviews to be available on Android TV. When I visit play store from my desktop browser using [Clear TV Web Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iberapps.cleartvwebbrowser) I can see list of compatible devices so I can install the app on any of them.

However when I check app store on my Android TV device, there is very few apps listed and my browser is not visible.

I am guessing there is some additional step that I missed, since approved app compatible with the device should be visible there. Unless my app is visible in store on the device itself it won't be accessible to wider audience, which is less than optimal.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Update: AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.iberapps.cleartvwebbrowser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:versionCode="6"
        android:versionName="1.0.6"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ClearTVWebBrowser"
        android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_clear2"
        android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_clear2">
        <activity
            android:name="com.iberapps.cleartvwebbrowser.ControlsActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.iberapps.cleartvwebbrowser.MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_clear2"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_clear2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_clear2"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iberapps.cleartvwebbrowser.SearchEngineActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest-  anything that mentions uses-, features, or screen sizes.  That's generally what restricts things from the play store.  We don't need all of your activities/services, we need the metadata parts.

Comment: I don't know if its the problem, but I wouldn't add thing like "uses-feature touchscreen".  I get that you're trying to say it doesn't need it, but Play seems to have fewer issues if you only mention absolutely necessary features rather than things you don't need.  Same with leanback-  will your app not work without it?  If not don't mention it in the manifest.  These aren't permissions, they're filters for the play store.

Comment: That manifest is verbatim copy of what is minimal requirement for Android TV app, in order to pass additional review. If I require touchscreen it won't be TV compatible, same as leanback* stuff which is absolutely required. Thanks and please feel free to shoot any ideas this way. There has to be something to actually see the approved app in store on the compatible device. (I am not guessing about compatible device btw, there is list of device models with my box included and desktop play store says it is compatible)

Comment: Alternatively, is there any decently reliable way to directly ask google? Any links or success in that direction highly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't say you should require touchscreen, I said you should remove it.  That leaves it as neither required nor forbidden. If you don't see the app in the play store on the device, that's because the play store thinks your device isn't compatible.

Comment: I understand that but when I click on that app store link using desktop web browser, there is "This app is available for some of your devices" link (right on app store page) and it lists all my compatible Android TV devices. If desktop app store says app is compatible with the device shouldn't device follow the same logic? Please see https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start, 'Declare leanback support" and "Declare touchscreen not required" and let me know if you spot anything.

Comment: I have the same issue wherein the app is live, but TV devices have failed review. There is no Email from Google as well. All the google policies have been adhered to. 
The app is live on mobile and also the TV build is accepted but in the device catalog, it shows a review failed but there is no specific reason mentioned. 

I have been stuck on this issue for a while now, I tried submitting new builds thinking it might be a glitch on Google's side but no success. 

PS: Leanback is set to True and touchscreen is set to False.

Does anyone know the way ahead?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to split discussion into chats, maybe somebody else has the ability to do that. @DarshanKarekar please open separate question since your problem doesn't look like this one at all. Google is sending detailed problem description with every rejection of TV app so check your dev email. It is not 'the same issue".